# Select entire element except specific element inside main

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I have the main div (modal-container) which taking a full page and inside the main div and having another div (modal-inner) with two buttons. The main DIV was set to full height/width of the page and inside DIV (modal-inner) having calc(100% - 40px) width of screen.

Through Jquery I have added two functions on each button click event, like jq-button-ok & jq-button-cancel. Now when I try to add a click event into a modal-container but its call two buttons click function too at the same time. What would be the solution?

HTML:

```
<div class="modal-container" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-inner" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button class="button jq-button-ok">OK</button>
                <button class="button jq-button-cancel">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.modal-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 102;
    background: rgba(216,216,216,.25);
    transition: 0.3s opacity ease-in;
    opacity: 1;
}

.modal-inner {
    position: static;
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    max-width: calc(100% - 20px);
    transition: none;
    transform: none;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("body").on("click", ".jq-button-ok", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            callfunstionone();
        });

        $("body").on("click", ".jq-button-cancel", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            callfunstiontwo();
        });

        $("body").on("click", ".modal-container:not(.modal-inner)", function (e) {
            callfunstionfour();
        });

    });
```

Comment: Why not use different classes for outer/inner buttons?

Comment: You have not actually asked a question.

Comment: This sounds like you have misunderstood what the selector `.modal-container:not(.modal-inner)` does to begin with. Were you thinking this was a way to bind that click handler to `.modal-container` only, but not have it fire when any descendants are clicked? That’s not how things work.  Events _bubble_ up the DOM, unless you do something about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `e​.prevent​Default()`, you should use [`e.stop​Propagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation):

> The `stopPropagation()` method of the Event interface prevents further propagation of the current event in the ***capturing*** and ***bubbling*** phases.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("body").on("click", ".jq-button-ok", function (e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      //callfunstionone();
      alert('You have clicked button-ok')
  });

  $("body").on("click", ".jq-button-cancel", function (e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      //callfunstiontwo();
      alert('You have clicked cancel')
  });

  $("body").on("click", ".modal-container:not(.modal-inner)", function (e) {
      //callfunstionfour();
      alert('You have clicked modal-container but not modal-inner')
  });

});
```

```css
.modal-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 102;
    background: rgba(216,216,216,.25);
    transition: 0.3s opacity ease-in;
    opacity: 1;
}

.modal-inner {
    position: static;
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    max-width: calc(100% - 20px);
    transition: none;
    transform: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-container" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-inner" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button class="button jq-button-ok">OK</button>
        <button class="button jq-button-cancel">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of registering multiple

```
$("body").on("click", ...
```

events, just register the stuff you actually need. Also you can use

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

to stop bubbling:

```
$(".jq-button-ok").on("click", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    callfunstionone();
});

$(".jq-button-cancel").on("click", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    callfunstiontwo();
});

$(".modal-container").on("click", function (e) {
    callfunstionfour();
});
```

---

<kbd>[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/015yq6k3/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The click event is propagating up the dom from the button to the div so both elements event handler gets triggered. You can stop the propagation with `Event.stopImmediatePropagation`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("body").on("click", ".jq-button-ok", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('callfunstionone()');
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        });

        $("body").on("click", ".jq-button-cancel", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('callfunstiontwo()');
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();

        });

        $("body").on("click", ".modal-container", function (e) {
            console.log('callfunstionfour()');
        });

    });
```

```css
.modal-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 102;
    background: rgba(216,216,216,.25);
    transition: 0.3s opacity ease-in;
    opacity: 1;
}

.modal-inner {
    position: static;
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    max-width: calc(100% - 20px);
    transition: none;
    transform: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-container" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-inner" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button class="button jq-button-ok">OK</button>
                <button class="button jq-button-cancel">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to exclude the buttons you want to exclude:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("body").on("click", ".jq-button-ok", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            callfunstionone();
        });

        $("body").on("click", ".jq-button-cancel", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            callfunstiontwo();
        });

        $("body").on("click", ".modal-container:not(.jq-button-ok):not(.jq-button-cancel)", function (e) {
            callfunstionfour();
        });

    });
```

Comment: @NullDev thanks for the comment, edited my answer accordingly.